# jQuery DataTable JSON Parsing Error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Okay, so, my issue today is I am trying to return a jquery datatable from a AJAX result, and every time I request the AJAX I am getting the following error:

"DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error"

Here is what my view looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var oTable = $('#StudentTable').dataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "Admin/FindStudent",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "sName": "StudentID",
                        "bSearchable": false,
                        "bSortable": false,
                        "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                            return '<a href=\"Student/Details/' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">View</a>';
                        }
                    },
                    { "sName": "FirstName" },
                    { "sName": "LastName" },
                    { "sName": "EmailAddress" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
<table id="StudentTable" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email Address</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult FindStudent(DataTableParamModel dtParams)
    {

        //if (Session["IsAdmin"] != "True")
        //{
        //    return View("Login");
        //}

        var repo = new StudentRepository();
        var allStudents = repo.GetAllStudents();
        IEnumerable<StudentInfo> filteredStudents;
        //Check whether the students should be filtered by keyword
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtParams.sSearch))
        {
            //Used if particulare columns are filtered 
            var fnameFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_1"]);
            var lnameFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_2"]);
            var emailFilter = Convert.ToString(Request["sSearch_3"]);

            //Optionally check whether the columns are searchable at all 
            var isFNameSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_1"]);
            var isLNameSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_2"]);
            var isEmailSearchable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSearchable_3"]);

            filteredStudents = repo.GetAllStudents()
               .Where(c => isFNameSearchable && c.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(dtParams.sSearch.ToLower())
                           ||
                           isLNameSearchable && c.LastName.ToLower().Contains(dtParams.sSearch.ToLower())
                           ||
                           isEmailSearchable && c.EmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(dtParams.sSearch.ToLower()));
        }
        else
        {
            filteredStudents = allStudents;
        }

        var isFNameSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_1"]);
        var isLNameSortable = Convert.ToBoolean(Request["bSortable_2"]);
        var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
        Func<StudentInfo, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 && isFNameSortable ? c.FirstName :
                                                       sortColumnIndex == 2 && isLNameSortable ? c.LastName :
                                                       "");

        var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"]; // asc or desc
        if (sortDirection == "asc")
            filteredStudents = filteredStudents.OrderBy(orderingFunction);
        else
            filteredStudents = filteredStudents.OrderByDescending(orderingFunction);

        var displayedStudents = filteredStudents.Skip(dtParams.iDisplayStart).Take(dtParams.iDisplayLength);
        var result = from c in displayedStudents select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.StudentID), c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.EmailAddress };
        JsonResult results = Json(new
                        {
                            sEcho = dtParams.sEcho,
                            iTotalRecords = allStudents.Count(),
                            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredStudents.Count(),
                            aaData = result
                        },
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return View(results);
    }
```

When using JSONLint, it spits out

```
Parse error on line 1:
<headid="Head1"><sty
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

Any ideas?

Comment: **`<headid="Head1"><sty`** does not look like json. It can be an html page or xml

Comment: Well, that's obvious. But no where in my view do I have that head tag. It appears it is being appended by the actually jquery datatable JS. But I cannot figure out how to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

try to return Json object:

```
return Json(new {
         sEcho = dtParams.sEcho,
         iTotalRecords = allStudents.Count(),
         iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredStudents.Count(),
         aaData = result
   }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

[resource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part)

Comment: Actually, I have the issue figured out. I just don't know the solution. The underlying issue is the actual view is being loaded through AJAX as well, which is why I passed the JSON result to the view. So, how would I go about making it work in this setup?

Comment: you can upload data to the datatable by ajax or view by ajax. are two separate things. you can load the view without data, and then call ajax data table by ajax. see this example http://goo.gl/ErFae

Comment: when you view the loaded data, just applying the plugin without `sAjaxSource`, but if you have the view without data, you have to use `sAjaxSource`

Comment: Thanks Andres, that helped me out .